# LazyVStack in ScrollView has jittery auto scroll

Tags: swiftui, scrollviewreader

I have a chat app, where whenever a chat room is opened, I need the view to scroll to the bottom as soon as the messages are fetched.

The thing is that although it does scroll perfectly when a new message is received or sent (see `ViewModel` down below), it is very jittery when I tell it to scroll right after the first batch of messages is fetched, which happens once as soon as the view appears.

After a lot of trial and error, I realized that if I add a small delay to the scroll, it'll improve but not completely! It is like it's trying to scroll to the very bottom, but it'll fail just for a few inches. I also realized that if I add a bigger delay, like 2 seconds, it'll scroll just fine.

Here's the messages list view:

```
    struct MessagesView: View {
        @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
        
        // -----------------------
        
        let currentChatRoom: ChatRoom
        
        // -----------------------
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                            LazyVStack {
                                ForEach(viewModel.messages) { message in
                                    MessageView(message: message)
                                        .id(message.id)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            viewModel.shouldDismissKeyboard = true
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            .onChange(of: viewModel.shouldScrollToMessageId) { messageId in
                                if let messageId = messageId, !messageId.isEmpty {
                                    proxy.scrollTo(messageId, anchor: .bottom)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        if chatEnvironment.isOtherUserTyping {
                            TypingIndicationView()
                        }
                        
                        BottomView()
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.setUp(currentChatRoom: currentChatRoom)
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it’s `viewModel.shouldScrollToMessageId` that’s responsible for "auto-scrolling" to the last message.

Here’s `MessageView`:

```
    fileprivate struct MessageView: View {
        let message: Message
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                    Text(message.user.isCurrentUser == true ? "You" : "\(message.user.username)")
                        .foregroundColor(message.user.isCurrentUser == true ? .customGreen : .customBlue)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .font(.default(size: 16))
                        .padding(.bottom, 1)
                    
                    if let imageURL = message.postSource?.imageURL, !imageURL.isEmpty {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            WebImage(url: .init(string: imageURL))
                                .resizable()
                                .indicator(.activity)
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.45)
                                .cornerRadius(25)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Text(message.text)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .font(.default(size: 16))
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 8)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .background(
                Color.black
            )
        }
    }
```

Here’s the `ViewModel`:

```
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
            @Published var messages = [Message]()
            @Published var text = ""
            @Published var shouldScrollToMessageId: String?
            @Published var currentChatRoom: ChatRoom?
            
            // -----------------------------
            
            private var isInitialized = false
            
            // -----------------------------
            
            func setUp(currentChatRoom: ChatRoom) {
                guard !isInitialized else { return }
                isInitialized.toggle()
                
                // -----------------------------
                
                self.currentChatRoom = currentChatRoom
                
                // -----------------------------
                
                getFirstBatchOfMessages(chatRoom: chatRoom)
                subscribeToNewMessages()
            }
            
            private func getFirstBatchOfMessages(chatRoom: ChatRoom) {
                messagesService.getMessages(chatRoomId: chatRoom.id) { [weak self] messages in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.messages = messages
                    }
                    
                    self?.scrollToBottom(delay: 0.15)
                }
            }
    
            private func subscribeToNewMessages() {
                ...
                    
                if !newMessages.isEmpty {
                    self?.scrollToBottom(delay: 0)
                }
            }
            
            func scrollToBottom(delay: TimeInterval) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.shouldScrollToMessageId = self.messages.last?.id
                }
            }
            
            func sendMessage() {
                ...
    
                scrollToBottom(delay: 0)
            }
        }
```

Here, `scrollToBottom` is responsible for notifying the `MessagesView` that `shouldScrollToMessageId`'s value changed and that it should scroll to the last message.

Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible since it involves a backend (Firestore) as well :/ I mean that it won’t be "minimal" at all! What else could I add?

Answer (score 2):

I am also writing an application with a chat on SwiftUI and I also have a lot of headaches with a bunch of ScrollView and LazyVStack.

In my case, I load messages from the CoreData and display them in a LazyVStack, so in my case, scrolling to the last message does not work, it seems to me simply because a bottom last view did not render, because rendering starts from the top.

Therefore, I came up with a solution with placing an invisible view at the bottom and assigned it a static ID, in my case `-1`:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(messages) { message in
            MessageRowView(viewWidth: wholeViewProxy.size.width, message: message)
                .equatable()
        }
    }
                        
    Color.clear.id(-1)
        .padding(.bottom, inputViewHeight)
}
```

I call scroll to this view:

```
.onAppear {
    scrollTo(messageID: -1, animation: nil, scrollReader: scrollReader)
}
```

And it works... but sometimes...

Sometimes it works correctly, sometimes it stops without scrolling a couple of screens to the end. Looks like `LazyVStack` is rendering the next views after the `scrollTo` has finished its work. Also, if add scrolling with some delay it may works better, but not always perfect.

I hope this can be a little helpful and if you find a stable solution I will be very happy if you share :)